# View a command in the shell history

Tags: shell, command-history

If we put a space before any command in the shell it will not shown in history.

Is there any way to see that command if the user enters a space before any command?

Comment: cross-posted question [How can I find the command history if a user used a space before the command?](http://askubuntu.com/q/566534/283843)

Answer (score 2):

By default HISTIGNORE is set to ignore commands with spaces. Remove that configuration and it will remember commands with spaces.

If you set `HISTIGNORE=""` then the history will record everything. You can set it temporarily as so:

```
export HISTIGNORE=""
```

To make it permanent, then search your `.bashrc` file for the string `HISTIGNORE` and replace its configuration with `""`.

Comment: i want to know the command if user uses space before that command?

Comment: By default `HISTIGNORE` is set to ignore commands with spaces. Remove that configuration and it will remember commands with spaces.

Comment: This is cross-posted, as per the comment on the question, but FWIW my bashrc doesn't have `HISTIGNORE` by default, instead using `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`, as per my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/566536/53508) on AskUbuntu.